# how to convert from String to Clob in java using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my code

```
 public void saveWorkflowXml(Session session , String xml,long workflowId) throws Exception {

         Workflow wf =(Workflow) session.load(getPersistentClass() , workflowId);
         Clob xmlDiagram = (Clob) Hibernate.createClob(xml, session);
         xmlDiagram.setString(1, xml);
         wf.setXmlDiagram(xmlDiagram);
         session.update(wf);

}
```

it throws exception, any help ?

Comment: What Exception? Could you post a log?

Comment: ALso , did you use debugger to find out which line throws Exception, you will know which line and then you can find out via API documentation whether your usage for this is correct.

Comment: @hagubear There is no need for a debugger to know the exact line the exception gets thrown. The stack trace tells it already.

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken

Comment: Looks like a ClassLoader issue.

Comment: @abeermahmoud, post complete stacktrace of the exception to your question.

Comment: Voted to close.  It is not possible to provide a meaningful answer to this question without a full stacktrace.

Comment: error
java.lang.Exception: com.si.ecm.core.exception.WorkflowEngineException: WorkflowStepHandlerManager::OperationTypeHandler : org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken
atcom.si.ecm.app.workflow.diagram.bo.Diagram.doProcess(Diagram.java:47)
om.si.ecm.app.workflow.diagram.servlet.WorkflowDiagramHandlerServlet.doView(WorkflowDiagramHandlerServlet.java:38)
at com.si.ecm.core.servlet.CoreServlet.doPost(CoreServlet.java:110)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)

Comment: @abeermahmoud, edit your question and post complete stacktrace of the exception properly.